# Помогите пожалуйста с установкой PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, 1с, windows-server

Всем здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста. Поставил 1с сервер на windows server 2012, ставлю PostgreSQL и при установке выходит ошибка

**Не удалось запустить intidb: -1073741515!
Пожалуйста, посмотрите файл 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12.7-1.1C\tmp\initdb.log' для детальной информации.**

Указанный файл при этом пустой.

При нажатии ОК происходит откат и всплывает сообщение

Расположение недоступно

***Файл C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL недоступен. Если он находится на этом компьютере, убедитесь, что диск подключен или вставлен, и попробуйте еще раз. Если это сетевой файл, проверьте, подключены ли вы к сети или к Интернету, и повторите попытку. Если не удается найти файл, возможно, он был перемещен или удален.***

Может кто подсказать, в чем причина?

Comment: Первое что бы я проверил: Запуск от имени администратора ?!

Answer (score 1):

на будущее, кто столкнётся с этой же проблемой, поставьте сначала vcredist_x64.exe из комплекта, а потом уже запускайте установку PostgreSQL